# Sony PCM-D100 Mic In

Tags: sound, portable-recorder, sony, pcm, device

here is a question I also asked on gearslutz:

I'm planning to build my first field recording rig. I already have a 416 + Blimp.
Until now, my plan was to get a SD 702 and a Sony PCM-M 10.
For me, a pocket recorder for spontaneous recordings is at least equally important as 'planned' recordings with external mics.

I read about the new PCM-D100 which is said to have excellent internal mics (an upgrade to the PCM-M10).
Concerning the external mic Input, I found a comparison between a D50 and a 744 with the conclusion that the Sony performs pretty good.
http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.de/2011/03/quickie-shootout-744t-vs-pcm-d50-with.html

Another test of the D50 also made a good impression:
http://www.homebrewedmusic.com/2011/09/09/field-recorders-external-mic-input-pcm-d50-h2n-h2-all-with-nt4/

My question is, is the combination Denecke PS-2 / PCM-D100 really as good as some say (especially compared to a Sound Devices if portability isn't an issue).
Another question is, will the stereo mic Input accept two external mics connected via *Denecke PS-2 and 2x XLR to stereo jack* or just one? If two, is the D100 also capable of recording two seperate channels for each mic (and not a mix of both)?

Since a 702 + PCM-M10 will cost me about 1400€ and the PS-2 + PCM-D100 about 650€, I could save a lot of money for future upgrades.

Update:
The D100 itself should serve as a pocket recorder I'll always have with me. But it should be able to record usable sounds I could also add to my library.
The external mics are intended for recordings mostly at home or in 
controlled areas. I mostly want to record ambiances (quiet to loud) and simple effects. 
Extreme conditions, extreme efects (expolsions etc.) and production sound aren't my focus.

Comment: This is Sound Design for sound design, editing, etc.

Comment: Hi Luke, you've commented on another post that it's off-topic. We should discuss this in meta.

Comment: Since I've seen a lot of questions about gear, I thought this is the right  place to ask. Sorry if not.

Answer (score 1):

First off I think it's a big decision to buy a field recording rig. It's very good that you ask about these things, because it can prevent you from buying the wrong gear for the purpose. But you never mentioned your purpose of buying it in the first place. What do you plan to record? Quiet Ambiences or cars?

```
My question is, is the combination Denecke PS-2 / PCM-D100 really as good as some say (especially compared to a Sound Devices if portability isn't an issue). Another question is, will the mic Input accept two external mics connected via Denecke PS-2 and adapters or just one? If two, is the D100 also capable of recording two seperate channels for each mic (and not a mix of both)?
```

1. A sound devices is a solid piece of engineering for the field, to work in any condition or situation (within limits ofcourse). Going to the arctic, take sound devices instead of the 'mixed-bag'.
2. If the denecke outputs 2 channels and the d100 accepts 2 inputs, you're good to go!
3. Ofcourse it records discretely, it's a stereo recorder :)

Please update your question with the purpose of the kit.

Comment: Thanks so far, I've updated my question.
to 2) the mic In is stereo, and the denecke outputs 2 x XLR, so it should be fine wit a Y-Cable. I just want to go sure.